# Import Errors when first few cells are BLANK

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I'm trying to export data to my Access database from MS Excel using VBA.

Everything uploads fine except for two columns (ACT_FORBRNCE_DESC & ACT_FORBRNCE_STATUS_DESC) which both error out due to Type Conversion Failure. I know this is due to the first 25 rows being BLANK and later on in the file, there are non-BLANKs. I've tried to convert the column to TEXT format but it still errors out.

I can't seem to find a solution to this online - does anyone have any ideas?

FYI using dummy data is not a viable solution here in this instance.

[image: Import Errors]

Comment: Can you convert at query stage, so cstr(ACT_FORBRNCE_DESC) or some capture of nulls in this field.  May be better to build off a query of the table rather than the table to ensure conversions

Comment: Do these errors have any other affect, besides being registered in the ImortErrors table?

Comment: What type of data do those two columns hold?

Comment: @marlan the only issue is that these column cell values are not available in the Access table.

Comment: @KostasK. String Values.

Comment: One possible solution is to use Excel to save the file as text and then load it in Access using a file input specification.

Comment: something like `SELECT XL1.* into [MyNewTable] FROM [Excel 12.0;HDR=No; Database=C:\TESTING.xlsx].[Sheet1$a1:a1000] AS XL1` or `INSERT INTO [MyTable] SELECT XL1.* FROM [Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes; Database=C:\TESTING.xlsx].[Sheet1$a3:a1000] AS XL1`  This will allow you to modify the fields and capture any nulls.

Comment: Do you have control over the destination data type too? you can avoid data conversion by having identical sours and destination data types.

Answer (score 1):

Using the following as my Excel source

[image]

I then used the following in Access

`SELECT Nz(FieldWithBlanks,"") AS Expr1, XL1.Field1, XL1.Field2 into newtable FROM [Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes; Database=C:\Databases\SO123.xlsx].[Sheet1$a1:c6] AS XL1;`

Which gave the following

[image]

Comment: I think you are _linking_ to an external file? OP's issue is _importing_ the data.

Comment: Yes, importing from Excel to Access "I'm trying to export data to my Access database from MS Excel using VBA."

Comment: Oh I got you. So OP could build an INSERT to his local table statement on top of your SELECT statement, or even just use your query instead of a local table. That's pretty slick.

Comment: Yeah, use select into or insert into